# Responsive Image for mobile

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

Can i put media queries for image like that. I mean it works but i wonder if it looks absurd.
Because my image looks so small in mobile. Also vh didnt work.

```
 .banner {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 185px;
    max-height: 270px;
  }
```

Comment: Can you be splease more precise ? `Also vh didnt work` what didn't work? What do you expect for result ?

Comment: he means viewport height (vh) didn't work.  Still not enough information.

Comment: I mean I opened device toolbar and then expand it higher width , vh caused problems. There was space between picture and max-width like that 
https://prnt.sc/qoa5gu 
I know that max-width: 100% is right for images but how should i use height? 
And also can i use media queries for them?

Answer (score 1):

Personally out of preference if the image isn't the right dimensions for a banner I would set it as a `background-image` to `<div>`. This way you can set it to cover the area and center it, you will lose area's of the image but at the same time, it will always cover the area and work responsively.

```
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    /* can also set to 100vw if you wish */
    /* specify height - this is a personal favourite of mine at times */
    height: calc(100vh - 185px);
    /* if you wish to keep max-height */
    max-height: 270px;

    background-image: url('[insert route to image file]');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

The changed markup if you need it

```
<div class="banner">
  <!-- insert any child elements if needed -->
</div>
```

If you wish to set further media queries and you are working with a mobile first design with 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` set in your `<head>` then use them like so

Tablet Media Query

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/* Set new styles here */
}
```

Desktop Media Query

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
 /* Set new styles here */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.I want to create banner starts with 180px height in mobile and grows until 1280px and then it will be 445px height I used min-width: 100% and height: auto. It works pretty good for 1280+ (exactly 445px height because my image is 450px height) but when i look to mobile it is 150 px. Smaller than i expect. I am confused should i use media query for it or not.

Comment: As a side note, you can use cover and contain on image with the property "object-fit" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Comment: This is true, but object-fit is not supported by any version of IE. https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: Which is just one more reason to stop supporting IE.

Comment: Haha don't even get me started, I've been doing IE fixes & poly-filling for the past day or two 

Answer (score 1):

Not absurd, but if you're not getting the desired effect, it is wrong. There are many ways you could implement your banner, the easiest (I'd think) would be:

```
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 185px; {/* or whatever */}
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Or adding it as a background image and using "background-size: cover", as preposed by Oliver.

Another possibility would be to add them as background images and using media queries to load different images. This would allow you to load images that better [fit the screen size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width) and [pixel density](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution) (art direction), and you'd get better quality in exchange for the extra work. For example:

```
@media (min-width: 35rem) and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
    .banner {
        background-image: url('foo.bar');
    }
}
```

Personally, I think media queries are great *when you need them*. If you can do the job with relative units, you avoid spreading around bits of the css that would be more maintainable together.

Now I must say the cool kids use another trick: responsive images. The examples below are from [the MDN article.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) In you html you can add different sources for an image via "scrset" and "sizes" attributes:

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

In that case, the sizes attribute acts something like a media query to help the browser detect and ask for the best fit image.

Alternatively, you can use the `<picture>` tag with different sources, allowing you to use the media that best fit the user device. For example:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
</picture>
```

These responsive image techniques exist because images in html are preloaded before your css, media queries and background images urls can kick in, so they basically load faster. It is a valid point, though, that transfering responsabilities from CSS to HTML because of performance issues goes against separation of concerns, but I'll let you be the judge on that.

And finally, about "vh" not working... it most certainly does. But we won't be able to help without a better description of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt know that i can use object-fit. By the way i thought about using background-image and i did little reasearch i did not clearly understand tho.I just want one image fills all width and its max-height(270px)  . Not sure which one is better but anyway i made it with image and used media query ^^. It works now. It does what i want but my media queries are getting bigger.

Comment: My concern is that if you're using the same image for mobile and desktop, it might be too pixelated on big screens, or unnecessarily large for mobile screens. Aside from that, you could avoid media queries (if you want, they're ok, really), by setting height: calc( 185px + 5vh ); max-height: 270px; for example.